# Is it possible to open two seprate browser windows using React Portal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

I am very new to React portals and wanted to unserstand if the following sceanrio is possible using React portal:

Secnarion:

1. OnClick on Button should open my component in new window(let's say w1) using React portal
2. My component on w1 will some text and a button.
3. OnClick on this button should open another component in a new window(say w2) by using React portal

OnClcik on parent window open w1, OnClcik on w1 should open w2.

This is one of my requriement for my project so I wanted to know if this can be done by React portal? If not then is there anything I can do to achieve this in React?

On w1 I tried to open a new window with different div id using React Portal. But this is getting appened to existing content of w1 and soon gets disapper showing a blank window on w1